# How do I change the thumbnail size of a fotorama slider?

Tags: wordpress, fotorama

I've been using the Fotorama plugin to create a slider on my website. It works as it should, but I want to change the size of the thumbnails that are shown, and I can't figure out how. The website is: http://jeannebard.ch/?p=123.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the full list of options for fotorama here: http://fotorama.io/customize/options/

Options can be passed via data attributes:

```
<div class="fotorama"
     data-thumbwidth="120"
     data-thumbheight="120">
  <img src="1.jpg">
  <img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

...or JavaScript:

```
$('.fotorama').fotorama({
  thumbwidth: '120',
  thumbheight: '120'
});
```

...or the Shortcode if using the plugin version:

```
[gallery ids="1,2,3" nav="thumbs" thumbwidth="120" thumbheight="120"]
```

This example would set the thumbnails twice their current size, to 120x120.

Comment: I want to do like that if 4 or more than 4 image available in thumbnail then display next/prev arrow with slider as like main image. can you please help me? @michaelrmcneill

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default thumbnail size via the WordPress admin area.

Go to: `Settings > Media`

**Update:** The Fotorama plugin doesn't seem to use the WordPress media settings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24705223/1709033) instead for an alternative answer.

Comment: The OP asked about the the [fotorama](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fotorama/) plugin, not the built in WordPress [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Comment: @michaelrmcneill that part was already clear to me. So are you saying the Fotorama plugin does not honour the WordPress media settings?

Comment: That is correct. The WordPress media settings don't apply to the plugin, because it is displaying the thumbs in a slider. It utilizes its own options to control the sizing of those (with the default being 60x60.)

Comment: Humm.. To disregard such settings make little sense. Thanks for pointing it out.